# compare two mysql sql performance?

Tags: mysql

```
select * from goods where (name like '%%' or brand '%%' or alias like '%%') and category_id = 1 order by id limit 20

select * from goods where category_id = 1 order by id limit 20;
```

Mysql version `5.6.16-log`, Does above two sql has same performance?

Business background, user could search goods by keyword or category or both, if user does not input keyword then keyword parameter default is empty string. I want to use the same sql, but worry performance. If keyword is empty should has a special query sql?

Comment: There is no comparison as both have different conditions, not all conditions exists in second one.

Comment: try enabling profiling for both queries to see the overall information - "SET profiling = 1; "

Comment: @Commenters & Answerers, the point of OP is, whether MySQL will internally optimize the `name like '%%' or brand '%%' or alias like '%%'` query ?, so that the resultant time will be same as Second query if there is no data present inside `%%` of the like query..

Comment: @user1354678 But how do I know mysql whether optimize it internally

Answer (score 2):

You could measure it using a profile; here the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html

Start the profiler with

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

Then execute your Query. With

`SHOW PROFILES;`

you see a list of queries the profiler has statistics for. And finally you choose which query to examine with

```
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
```

or whatever number your query has.

What you get is a list where exactly how much time was spent during the query. Then you can decide which one was more perfomant

Comment: Thanks!Query_ID: 1
Duration: 0.00056225;Query_ID: 2
Duration: 0.00079900 May be my data is too small(5882)

Answer (score -2):

The second one should be faster because it has less conditions to consider and process.

Comment: but I used explain to check both sql, find the output is same

Comment: @zhuguowei Your data is too small to notice the difference. You should use a profiler asTechTreeDev suggested